# Can pyramid.arima.auto_arima autodetect seasonality and return p,q,d if non seasonal and P,Q,D if seasonal?

Tags: python, pyramid-arima

I have time series data that sometimes have seasonality and sometimes not. When it's seasonal, it can be of any pattern (daily, weekly, bi-weekly, etc.). I'd like to use auto_arima to

1) detect if there is any seasonality

2) know what is the cycle/pattern

3) know the P,D,Q of the model

Wasn't able to find related examples. Anyone has done this before? Thank you!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've been researching examples online, but all the examples have to specify in the params if it's a seasonal arima or not.